# Error : System.QueryException: Aggregate query has too many rows for direct assignment, use FOR loop

Tags: error

Facing an error : System.QueryException: Aggregate query has too many rows for direct assignment, use FOR loop. I kept tyring various ways like adddays method of date to overcome negative value (-30) from custom label.

```
  public class Account_CloneCasesOnAnniversary implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
   String errors = '';
   integer todayday = date.today().day();
   Integer currentmonth = date.today().month();

   public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
       return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Anniversary__c, NSCHBC__c, Status__c, ID, (SELECT Id, Anniversary__c, OwnerId, ContactId, ContactEmail, ContactPhone, Description, Priority, RecordTypeId, Subject FROM cases order by CreatedDate) from Account WHERE DAY_IN_MONTH(Anniversary__c) =:todayday AND CALENDAR_MONTH(Anniversary__c ) =: currentmonth');
      }

   public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> scope) {

    Id CRS_Master_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(Label.CRS_Review_MAP).getRecordTypeId();
    Id QCR_Master_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(Label.QCR_MAP).getRecordTypeId();
    Id NSCHBC_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('NSCHBC Action Plan').getRecordTypeId();

    if(scope.isEmpty()) return;

    Map<Id, Case> clonedCasesMap = new Map<Id,Case>();
    Map<Id, list<Case>> NSCHBCAccountToCasesMap = new Map<Id, list<Case>>();
    for(Account account : scope) {
        // Clone cases on Anniversary
        if(account.cases!=null && account.cases.size() > 0) {
            list<Case> lstCase = new list<Case>();
            for(Case objcase : account.cases){
                // Fetch only those Cases to be cloned whose Record type is of 
                if(objcase.RecordTypeId == CRS_Master_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId
                || objcase.RecordTypeId == QCR_Master_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId
                || objcase.RecordTypeId == NSCHBC_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId){ 
                    Case cloneCase = new Case();
                    cloneCase  = objcase.clone();
                    clonedCasesMap.put(objcase.Id,cloneCase);
                }
            }
        }

        // Check whether Account is of NSCHBS type
        if(account.NSCHBC__c && account.Status__c == 'Active') {
            NSCHBCAccountToCasesMap.put(account.Id, account.cases);
        }
    }

    if(!clonedCasesMap.isEmpty()) {
        Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(clonedCasesMap.values(), false);
        Integer index = 0;

        for(Database.SaveResult result : srList ) {
            if(!result.isSuccess()) {
                String errMsg = result.getErrors()[0].getMessage();
            } 
            index++;
        }
    }

    // create task on cases
    List<Task> taskCreateList = new List<Task>();
    if(!NSCHBCAccountToCasesMap.isEmpty()) {
        for(Id accountId : NSCHBCAccountToCasesMap.keyset()){

            try {
                if(NSCHBCAccountToCasesMap.get(accountId) != null && NSCHBCAccountToCasesMap.get(accountId).size() > 0) {
                    for(Case caseObj : NSCHBCAccountToCasesMap.get(accountId)) {
                       if(caseObj.RecordTypeId == NSCHBC_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId) {
                        Task createTask = new Task();
                        createTask.WhatId = caseObj.Id;
                        createTask.subject = 'QCR Anniversary';
                        createTask.ActivityDate = caseObj.Anniversary__c.adddays(integer.valueof(Label.Number_Of_Days)); // ERROR comes from here as have placed -30 value in custom label 
                        createTask.OwnerId = caseObj.OwnerId;
                        taskCreateList.add(createTask);
                       }                      
                    }
                 }
                }catch(Exception e) {
                   System.debug('An exception occurred: ' + e.getMessage());            
                }
            }            
       }        

    // check for task list is empty or not
    if(!taskCreateList.isEmpty()) {
        // insert task list Of Task which were cloned  
        Database.SaveResult[] srListTask = Database.insert(taskCreateList, false);
        Integer indexTask = 0;

        for(Database.SaveResult resultTask : srListTask ) {
            if(!resultTask.isSuccess()) {
                String errMsgTask = resultTask.getErrors()[0].getMessage();
            } 
            indexTask++;
        } 
    }
}

public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {

  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the error being thrown? Did you do as the error suggested? Did you do a search on the error?

Comment: As soon as I entered negative value (-30) in custom label instead of 30. It starts giving me an error with the changes made at line :                         createTask.ActivityDate = caseObj.Anniversary__c.adddays(integer.valueof(Label.Number_Of_Days)); // ERROR comes from here as have placed -30 value in custom label

Comment: According to the debug log, the error isn’t associated with any specific line of code: the error just appears at the end of the debug log, after my query has apparently executed successfully. And, of course, because of the error, the transaction rolls back and my database updates are gone.

Comment: Can you post relevant portion of debug log with statements befor and after error

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem.  A quick search turned up [this post](http://salesforcekings.blogspot.com/2015/07/systemqueryexception-aggregate-query.html).

The error seems to be related to dereferencing a to-many relationship on an sObject record where the to-many has over 200 children (too many children - ha!)

The list of children cannot be used in anyway except in a `for` loop.

I think your problem is in the following line (which is very similar to mine):

```
    if(account.cases!=null && account.cases.size() > 0) {
```

`account.cases` is probably too large.  But remember - if you retrieve an sObject through SOQL as you are doing, you can never have a null list - they are simply empty, and there's no pentaly for iterating over an empty list.

I'd suggest removing the safety check there and just going straight into your `for` loop.  Should work okay unless you are calling this `execute` method from somewhere else (which you shouldn't do).