# Inconsistency with error "Aggregate query has too many rows for direct assignment"

Tags: dynamic-soql, aggregate, querylocator, queryexception

I have a Box__c record with 100 Doors__r, 104 Motors__r, and 0 Wheels__r.

**ISSUE #1**

I am getting the error

> System.QueryException: Aggregate query has too many rows for direct assignment, use FOR loop

with the following code:

```
string q = 'select Id, ' +
           '(select id from Doors__r), ' +
           '(select id from Wheels__r), ' +
           '(select id from Motors__r) ' +
           'from Box__c where id =\'a0XX000000T5fnZZZS\'';

Database.QueryLocator locator = Database.getQueryLocator(q);
Database.QueryLocatorIterator it = locator.iterator();

while (it.hasNext())
{
    SObject l = it.next();
    l.getSObjects('Doors__r'); // error!
}
```

Why is it complaining about aggregate query when there is none?

**ISSUE #2**

The error goes away when the `Wheels__r` sub-query is removed. Why?

**ISSUE #3**

If I remove the `QueryLocator` the error goes away:

```
SObject[] ls = Database.query(q);

for (SObject l : ls)
{
    l.getSObjects('Doors__r');
}
```

Why is that?

**ISSUE #4**

I am not able to replicate these issues in a different org (using different objects but same record counts). What could be the reason?

Answer (score 4):

Salesforce, from time to time, uses some not-so-clear wording and terminology. A perfect example is "Aggregate" queries. You might think that an "Aggregate" query is one that uses Aggregate functions like `COUNT()` or `MIN()` along with `GROUP BY`.

That's completely logical (heck, you even get an `AggregateResult[]` from a query that uses Aggregate functions), but incorrect (or, at least, incomplete).

In Salesforce's world, the "Aggregate" query in the error that you're getting is a subquery, something like a left outer join (parent-child subquery) or a semijoin (subquery in the `WHERE` clause).

Unfortunately, there isn't any official documentation that I can find that explains exactly why this happens.

Probably the best documentation I can find that is related to this issue is in two pages [Understanding Query Results](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_results.htm?search_text=querymore) and [SOQL for loops](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm). From the first page (emphasis mine):

> Subquery results are like regular query results in that **you might need to use queryMore() to retrieve all the records if there are many children**. For example, if you issue a query on accounts that includes a subquery, your client application must handle results from the subquery as well:
>
> 1. Perform the query on Account.
> 2. Iterate over the account QueryResult with queryMore().
> 3. For each account object, retrieve the contacts QueryResult.
> 4. Iterate over the child contacts, using queryMore() on each contact's QueryResult.

From the second page:

> You might get a QueryException in a SOQL for loop with the message `Aggregate query has too many rows for direct assignment, use FOR loop`. This exception is sometimes thrown when accessing a large set of child records (200 or more) of a retrieved sObject inside the loop, or when getting the size of such a record set. For example, the query in the following SOQL for loop retrieves child contacts for a particular account. If this account contains more than 200 child contacts, the statements in the for loop cause an exception.
>
> ```
> for (Account acct : [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts)
>                 FROM Account WHERE Id IN ('<ID value>')]) {
>     List<Contact> contactList = acct.Contacts; // Causes an error
>     Integer count = acct.Contacts.size(); // Causes an error
> }
> ```

So the error likely has something to do with chunking the retrieval of records returned by a query and queryMore(). Saying anything beyond that would probably be speculation.

Yours is the first situation that I've seen where this error has popped up having 200+ child records *spread across more than one child SObject*.

I can't give a satisfactory answer to your 2nd, 3rd, and 4th issues. The workaround for this error is to use a `for()` loop, as suggested. That would probably look like this in your case:

```
while (it.hasNext())
{
    SObject l = it.next();
    for(SObject child :l.getSObjects('Doors__r'))
    {
        // add child records to a collection, or perform
        //   some other computation/logic, one-by-one in here.
    }
}
```

Comment: I hear you. But as mentioned in issue #2 the error disappears when the sub-query for the child table with 0 records is removed. In other words in issues #1 and #2 the number of child records is the same. So I don't think it's about X number of records in one table vs spread across more than one.

I am already using a for-loop in my code (not posted). But I am trying to understand the reason behind the inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when I see an error of this type, I try to pull out the sub-queries and form top level queries. Also, you may have some luck modifying for or while loops as you have shown in this case.

I think you might over over this Apex Governor limit:
**For loop list batch size**    200

It also states [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/151628/urgent-help-error-system-queryexception-aggregate-query-has-too-many-rows-f) that: The list of children cannot be used in anyway except in a for loop.

Comment: Also, do all your orgs have the same relationships the objects?